# Logging ASP.net core Lambda Application logs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, logging, aws-lambda

I have a dot net core 2.2 Lambda Application. I want to trace the application logs and send it to Cloudwatch and loggly. What is the best possible way to do this.

Comment: You mean you are developing Lambda function in .NET core? are you using any built-in project template to do this?

Comment: yes I have developed a Lambda function using .Net core 2.1. I have used standard AWS lambda template which is provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: the lambda function method which is generated by the project template should give you access to a logger. that logger writes logs to AWS Cloudwatch logs.

Comment: Could you share some example

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/developing-net-core-aws-lambda-functions/

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-logging.html